# Simple searching on data in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, search, date

i'm having some troubles getting results by searching on date.

here's the format:

```
2006-03-25 23:27:12
```

if i'm searching i tried to use this:

```
select * from aol where QueryTime BETWEEN '2006-03-19 00:00:00' and '2006-03-18 00:00:00'
```

But i'm never getting any results :(

Answer (score 3):

Between requires lower value before and after greatest value of the range, otherwise it returns an empty resultset without any error.

```
select * from aol where QueryTime BETWEEN '2006-03-18 00:00:00' and '2006-03-19 00:00:00'
```

is the same of writing

```
select * from aol where QueryTime >= '2006-03-18 00:00:00' and QueryTime <= '2006-03-19 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the difference between the two dates:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30');
```

Or this may work as well.

```
SELECT something FROM tbl_name
-> WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= date_col;
```

Both of these examples came from [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).  They show a lot of different ways that you could do this.